# Confused why A-f keybinding does not work in neovim

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I'm trying to add some readline keybindings into insert mode, like below,

```
inoremap <C-B> <Left>
inoremap <C-F> <Right>
inoremap <A-B> <C-Left>
inoremap <A-F> <C-Right>
```

The fist two work fine. However, when I try `A-B`, it goes back one word but changes the mode
to normal mode. Also, `A-f` only acts as `Esc` key, changes the mode to normal mode.
I have other `Alt` keybindings but they work fine. not sure what is special about these two.

`NVIM v0.4.4`
`Debian buster/sid`

Edit: some more info

- terminal emulator: `alacritty v0.4.3`,
- I don't use tmux and the like,
- in terminal `alt` is `^[`
- in neovim `alt` is `M` for `meta`
- `TERM=xterm-256color`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please also mention which terminal emulator you're using. And, if possible, which `$TERM` value you have. Are you inside tmux or screen or similar? If on the shell you start a command such as `cat` and type `<Alt-F>` or `<Alt-B>`, what shows up? Inside Vim, in insert mode, what does the sequences `<Ctrl-V><Alt-F>` produce?

Comment: @filbranden Thank you! my terminal emulator is `alacritty v0.4.3`. I don't use tmux and the like. in `cat` I see `^[f` and `^[b` respectively for `A-f` and `A-b`. inside neovim `<Ctrl-V><Alt-F>` produces <M-f>! it seems, in neovim `alt` acts as meta but in terminal `alt` is some escape sequence, so there is no meta key to be pressed actually. I'll update the question with these information.

Comment: @filbranden sorry, I forgot. `echo $term` = `xterm-256color`

Comment: Thanks! You missed the `$TERM` setting... Also check what `:set term?` inside Vim says... `^[f` is pretty standard way to encode the Alt-F key, so I think it's just something that Vim is thinking your terminal does something special when in fact it doesn't... Also look at `:set termcap` and see if you spot anything unusual there (though it's usually a fairly long one.)

Comment: @filbranden These two commands give me an error of `Unknown option: term?` and `Unkown option: termcap`, respectively.

Comment: It's possible these are specific to Vim and not available on NeoVim...

Comment: Does it help if you set `export TERM=alacritty` in your terminal? Also maybe check if the behavior is different between Vim and NeoVim if you can... (If Vim works and NeoVim doesn't, perhaps file a bug in their issue tracker? Or maybe search for existing issues matching your situation in their tracker... Make sure you include "alacritty" in your search.)

Comment: @filbranden Ok. I'll check these. in vim, again alt is `^[` and `M` does not do the job. In vim `<C-left>` does not work, in my case at least. `set term?` gives `alacritty` as I changed it. `set termcap` outputs some information; which one I should check? So far I searched about this issue with both keywords `neovim` and `alacritty`, but haven't find a solution. I'll continue searching.

Comment: @filbranden sorry, i forgot again. `export TERM=alacritty` didn't help.

Comment: @filbranden I think I found pretty much what I needed. It's tim pope's `vim-rsi` plugin. It works in urxvt and xfce4-terminal. I havent checked it yet on alacritty since I moved to urxvt. Nevertheless, I'm not sure if this is the answer to the question or not. I'll put an edit in my question.

Comment: You should actually post that as an answer! I also thought of `:set esckeys`, you can take a look at whether that would solve this issue... In any case, glad you found a solution, please post it as an answer when you can.

Comment: @filbranden sorry for my late response. I'll take that as an answer. there is no `esckeys` in neovim (no tab completion). Thanks for your help and guidance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want readline in your vim/neovim (my goal of asking this question), simply use Tim Pope's [`vim-rsi` plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi).

Comment: Thanks for posting it as an answer!